# Personal Finance / Money management software for Mac OS

Tags: mac, finance, microsoft-money

I recently moved from Windows to Mac Os X and I need a Personal Finance software.
Main functionalities needed:

- track expenses and income, on credit cards, cash, current accounts
- report, classify, analyze the spending and income
- manage my financial portfolio (equities, mutual funds, ETF) with mark-to-market, evaluation of P&L, ...

I am based in Italy, therefore the application should have Euro as base currency.

I strongly doubt that the Online Banking of Italian banks can be interfaced with any existing application, therefore I will need to enter manually all transactions; therefore, manual input /transaction booking must be easy and effective.

I have read this: https://superuser.com/questions/1583/os-x-money-management-software
but it does not completely match with my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Koku](http://www.fadingred.com/koku/) is a surprisingly pleasant personal finance manager for OS X. Plus, it is  compatible with several well known personal finance manager file formats and can direct connect to certain financial institutions.

Comment: I've spent some time on the Koku website and the application looks very nice. Apparently it does not manage the Financial Portfolio, but for this I can survive with Excel. Thanks Mike for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

[GnuCash](http://www.gnucash.org/) is available for OS X. I have no opinion on the package but presume it is competent.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same dilemma recently. This is not a facetious answer, but finding nothing decent (at the time) for the Mac OS, I got BootCamp, Windows and Quicken. This meant that I can actually share data with my laptop, too. *However*, I up-voted Mike Anderson's suggestion of Koku, new since I last looked; it seems not bad and I'll give it a shot.